# Insert record in impala table based on datatype and column name

Tags: linux, shell, hadoop, hive, impala

I have some impala table which format is like this.

```
+--------------------------+-----------+---------+
| name                     | type      | comment |
+--------------------------+-----------+---------+
| col_key                   | bigint    |         |
| col_cd                    | smallint  |         |
| col_desc                  | string    |         |
| col_type_cd               | string    |         |
| col_scheme_cd             | string    |         |
| name                      | string    |         |
| source_cd                 | string    |         |
| source_cd1                | bigint    |         |
| load_dt                   | timestamp |         |
| effective_start_dt        | timestamp |         |
| effective_end_dt          | timestamp |         |
+--------------------------+-----------+---------+
```

I have to insert value like this

If datatype is

```
bigint then insert      0
smallint then insert    0
decimal then  insert    0.0
float then insert       0.0
string then insert      unknown
timestamp then insert   1970-01-01 00:00:00
```

and if the column name is

```
effective_start_dt then insert 1970-01-01 00:00:00
effective_end_dt then insert   3499-12-31 00:00:00
```

I have achieved one solution where, I am able to identify the datatype and based
on that I am inserting record but it is not working for my second condition where I am inserting record based on column name and inserting inserting `1970-01-01 00:00:00` vale for `effective_end_dt` too.

Looking for some help in this.
The column position may vary for others table therefore I am trying some generic solution. I am trying to achieve this solution from shell script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the string as a timestamp

```
cast("1979-01-01 00:00:00" as timestamp)
```